# Can't see form I created dynamiclly javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm new to javascript, and just trying to learn the basics of using it dynamiclly, not via the html file.

I'm trying to create a form dynamically on `js` so I have this in my html file :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>new Form</title>
        <LINK rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='Formstyle.css'></LINK>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src='form.js'></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

in my js file i have this

```
var f = document.createElement("form");
f.setAttribute('method',"post");
f.setAttribute('action',"submit.php");

var i = document.createElement("input");
i.type = "text";
i.name = "user_name";
```

but for some reason i'm running the file in chrome, but I get nothing.

Answer (score 3):

You created the form, but you never added it to the DOM (for that matter, you never added the input to the form either).

Use `appendChild` (or `insertBefore`, etc).

Answer (score 0):

you need to add your elements to your document

with something like `document.body.insertBefore`

Answer (score 0):

First, you should figure out where on the page you want the form to go. Let's say you want to append your input field or form to a "form" element.

To do this, you must do as the other say and append your dynamically created html to your DOM.

I made a codepen for you that adds an input field on click button:
http://codepen.io/alexG53090/pen/VeLpjd

```
HTML:
<div id='container'></div>
<button id='button'>click it</button>

JS:
var form = document.createElement('input');
var parent = document.getElementById('container');
container.appendChild(form);
```

Comment: Be careful @alex, There's no jquery tag in question.

Comment: Oh my, so sorry! Here's the same codepen but without jquery!!!! http://codepen.io/alexG53090/pen/VeLpjd